# api_key not defined in Jupyter notebook (youtube API v3)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, youtube-api

In line 1, I define the api_key:

```
api_key = "api text text here"
```

In line 2, I import build from google-api-client-python

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
```

In line 3 I write and execute the following

```
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key
```

And press Ctrl + Enter. I then get the following error:

```
 NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-746108c79ca9> in <module>
----> 1 youtube = build('youtube,' 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

NameError: name 'api_key' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the API key first

Comment: Please add some sample to get some better understanding.